# Bigram generation from JavaRDD<String>

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a list of words in `JavaRDD<String> words` now, how can I transform it into another `JavaRDD<String> NGram`, with a list of N-gram that formed by the previous list of words?

Here is the code I get by now:

```
List<String> word = words.collect();

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (word.size() - n + 1); i++){

        String nGram = word.get(i);
        for(int j = 1; j < n; j++){
            nGram = nGram + " " + word.get(i + j);
        }

        //Add n-gram to a list
        list.add(nGram);
    }

    JavaRDD<String> NGram = sc.parallelize(list);
```

However, I know that collecting a RDD into List is slow. I was wondering is there any method that we can transform the RDD `words` to RDD `NGram` directly?

Comment: What is the value of n?

Comment: Sorry for the confuse. n is the parameter of nGram. For example, if n = 2, then what we want is bigram.